# Desired GKE pod not found , google cloud composer

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I am using Google cloud composer ,and created composer environment.Composer environment is ready(has green tick), now I am trying to set variables used in DAG python code using google cloud shell.

command to set variables:

```
     gcloud composer environments run test-environment \
       --location us-central1 variables -- \
       --set gcp_project xxx-gcp
```

**Exact error message:**

```
  ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) Desired GKE pod not found. If the environment was recently started, please wait and retry.
```

I tried following things as part of investigation, but got same error each time.
I have created a new environment using UI and not google shell commands.
I checked pods in kubernetes engine and all are green , did not see any issue.
I verified composer API, Billing kubernetes, all required API's are enabled.

I have 'Editor' role assigned.

**added screenshot I saw first time some failures**

[image]

[image]

**Error with exit code 1**
google troubleshooting guide describe: If the exit code is 1, the container crashed because the application crashed.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of all pods running in your Composer environment's GKE cluster?

Comment: @hexacyanide added screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a side effect of Composer version 1.6.0 if you are using a [google-cloud-sdk](https://github.com/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk) that is too old, because it now launches pods in namespaces other than `default`. The error you see is a result of [looking for Kubernetes pods in the default namespace](https://github.com/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/blob/636d6c1b48f97c844aaa4cc2ddc8a5c2bb1be55e/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/composer/util.py#L314) and [failing to find them](https://github.com/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/blob/636d6c1b48f97c844aaa4cc2ddc8a5c2bb1be55e/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/composer/util.py#L275).

To fix this, run `gcloud components update`. If you cannot yet update, a workaround to execute Airflow commands is to manually SSH to a pod yourself and run `airflow`. To start, obtain GKE cluster credentials:

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials $COMPOSER_GKE_CLUSTER_NAME
```

Once you have the credentials, you should find which namespace the pods are running in (which you can also find using Cloud Console):

```
$ kubectl get namespaces
NAME                                    STATUS   AGE
composer-1-6-0-airflow-1-9-0-6f89fdb7   Active   17h
default                                 Active   17h
kube-public                             Active   17h
kube-system                             Active   17h
```

You can then SSH into any scheduler/worker pod, and run commands:

```
$ kubectl exec \
    --namespace=$NAMESPACE \
    -it airflow-worker-569bc59df5-x6jhl airflow list_dags -r
```

You can also open a shell if you prefer:

```
$ kubectl exec \
    --namespace=$NAMESPACE \
    -it airflow-worker-569bc59df5-x6jhl bash

airflow@airflow-worker-569bc59df5-x6jhl:~$ airflow list_dags -r
```

The failed `airflow-database-init-job` jobs are unrelated and will not cause problems in your Composer environment.

Comment: I was not able to SSH in pods , but this is helpful

Comment: Glad to hear -- I update the commands with more specific flags (like `--namespace`) in case you need to try again.

Comment: This is not really a regression, as @hexacyanide noticed, we now place airflow related workload inside a dedicated namespace since 1.6.0 and the gcloud SDK has been updated to take care of that. Please run gcloud components update and it should unblock you.